# How to display CommitDate instead of AuthorDate in tig main view

Tags: tig

The main tig view shows a very useful one-line-per-commit view with the AuthorDate in the first column.  Is it possible for this to display the CommitDate instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Tig only allows to display the date recorded for the author of a commit.

Comment: Is this still true in 2019? This is a necessary feature